# MSCK REPAIR TABLE working strangely on delta tables

Tags: amazon-athena, delta-lake

I have a delta table in s3 and for the same table, I have defined an external table in Athena. After creating the Athena table and generating manifests, I am loading the partitions using `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`. All the partition columns are in snake_case. But still, I am getting

> Partitions not in metastore.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: are you getting this directly after generation of manifest & MSCK?

Comment: Yes, when I download the output of MSCK, I see these lines in that file.

Comment: Did you check the error logs for athena query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. I was putting partition columns in wrong order while creating the table.

Answer (score 1):

The IAM user or role doesn't have a policy that allows the **glue:BatchCreatePartition** action. You have to allow **glue:BatchCreatePartition** in the IAM policy and it should work.

Comment: It is allowed in IAM policy, because similar thing is working with other delta tables.